# storing matrix in a c# dictionary

Tags: c#

I understand that a C# dictionary is basically a key:value pair

Is there a way to store matrix in a c# dictionary.

That is, can the key be a combination of two values (row, column)

For example

```
1 3
4 7

[0][0]:1, [0][1]:3, [1][0]:4, [1][1]:7
```

Can a dictionary be constructed for this? If so, how would I parse its elements. Things are much easier if key is a single value.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use an actual "matrix", as in a multidimensional array? `int[,] matrix = new int[3,3];'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Tuple<int,int>` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)) as the key, since the values need to be immutable to be accurate keys for a dictionary. The only thing that I would like to point out is that matrices tend to be used in situations where extracting values by row or by column, and you would not be able to do that if you stored them in this manner.

Have you considered using a library that defines matricies already? There are plenty of math libraries and helpers that do exactly that.

Comment: +1 - good comment on usage pattern and reminder on key being immutable (restriction is slightly less than "truly immutable" - not changing while used as key in dictionary, which for struct values requires to be immutable).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly: yes, you *could* store a matrix in a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, int> matrix;
```

But a much better way is to store a matrix as a 2-dimensional or jagged array.

```
int[,] matrix;    // 2-dmmensional
int[][] matrix;   // jagged
```

The only time an array may be inefficient is if the matrix is sparse (ie. has many missing values). In that case, you might consider using a Dictionary or maybe a List.

Comment: Depends on the scale of the matrix. If you have a very sparse data matrix then could be better to store in a dictionary

Comment: You demonstrated a jagged array, not a two dimensional array, which would be `int[,] matrix`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also store your matrix in a 2 dimensional array:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[2,2];
matrix[0,0] = 1;
matrix[0,1] = 3;
matrix[1,0] = 4;
matrix[1,1] = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `Dictionary` using `Tuple` class to store matrix:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, int>
```

Or even `KeyValuePair`:

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int>
```

But if you don't have any specific reason, you should use multi-dimensional array `int[,]`

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you can use a plain old multidimensional array, but since you asked:

```
var array = new int[,]
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9},
};
var query = 
    from row in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetUpperBound(0))
    from col in Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetUpperBound(1))
    select new KeyValuePair<Tuple<int,int>, int>(
                Tuple.Create(row,col), 
                array[row,col]);
var asDict = query.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```